# d3 Choropleth: Cannot read property 'objects' of undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a d3 choropleth that is throwing the error **"Cannot read property 'objects' of undefined"**.  How exactly do I go about testing this.  Not sure how `topojson` works either...

```
queue()

  // Load map JSON
  .defer(d3.json, 'https://rawgit.com/HyperrealTech/thorn-directives/master/lib/us.json')

  // Load applicable data
  .defer(d3.json, data)

  // Call rateById for each d in data
  .await(function(d) { 
    rateById.set(d.state, +d.count); 
  })

  // Once finished loading, call ready function
  .await(ready);

// Ready function
function ready(error, us) {

  // Append states to svg
  svg.append('g')
     .attr('class', 'states')
     .selectAll('path')
     .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states).features)
     .enter().append('path')
     .style('fill', function(d) {
        return color(rateById.get(d.state)); 
     })
     .attr('d', path)
```

Comment: My guess is that the JSON isn't loaded correctly.

Comment: But if you follow the JSON path, it seems to be working and loading perfectly fine.

Comment: Does it work if you use `d3.json` directly?

Comment: Do you mean w/ out queue?

Comment: Yes, to exclude anything that may be interfering.